# How can i add the numbers of tuples from different lists of a a list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.7

here's what i have (in python version 3.7.4):

```
P= [[('Lista-A', 1), ('Lista-X', 1), ('Lista-Z', 4)], [('Lista-A', 2), ('Lista-X', 0), ('Lista-Z', 1)], [('Lista-A', 5), ('Lista-X', 1), ('Lista-Z', 0)], [('Lista-A', 0), ('Lista-X', 1), ('Lista-Z', 4)]]
```

I'm trying to sum all the numbers associated with "Lista-A", "Lista-X" and "Lista-Z" so that I can get something like this (just a list of tuples that has the sum of the numbers associated with each "Lista"):

```
[('Lista-A', 8), ('Lista-X', 3), ('Lista-Z', 9)]
```

I've tried using a for cycle but I'm not getting there.

```
for lista in P:
        for i in lista:
```

I don't know how to continue the code... Can anyone help me? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: please edit your post and include your attempt with for cycle

Comment: Done! Don't know if it helps because I don't really know what to put under the for cylcle

Comment: "I don't know how to code this" is not a Stack Overflow question.  There's nothing in your code that attempts to sum the list elements.  [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  If you don't know how to identify and sum things, consider working through tutorials on grouping, sorting, and summation.  If you *do* know, then please make an honest try and post that.

Comment: I agree with @Prune, I suggest learning more about programming in general.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the "list names" are always in the same order, you can do this using a list comprehension with `zip` and `sum`:

```py
>>> data = [[('Lista-A', 1), ('Lista-X', 1), ('Lista-Z', 4)], [('Lista-A', 2), ('Lista-X', 0), ('Lista-Z', 1)], [('Lista-A', 5), ('Lista-X', 1), ('Lista-Z', 0)], [('Lista-A', 0), ('Lista-X', 1), ('Lista-Z', 4)]]
>>> [(col[0][0], sum(x for _, x in col)) for col in zip(*data)]
[('Lista-A', 8), ('Lista-X', 3), ('Lista-Z', 9)]
```

`zip(*data)` is a standard way to iterate over "columns" from a list of "rows". Assuming the columns do line up, then each column contains all the numbers to be summed for the same "list name". The `sum` function adds the numbers; the columns contain tuples where we want to sum the numbers in the second component, hence the destructuring assignment `_, x`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
from collections import defaultdict

input = [[('Lista-A', 1), ('Lista-X', 1), ('Lista-Z', 4)], [('Lista-A', 2), ('Lista-X', 0), ('Lista-Z', 1)], [('Lista-A', 5), ('Lista-X', 1), ('Lista-Z', 0)], [('Lista-A', 0), ('Lista-X', 1), ('Lista-Z', 4)]]

d = defaultdict(int)
for i in input:
    for j in i:
        d[j[0]] += j[1]

res = list(d.items())
```

Comment: I was trying to do something more simple using just "for cycle", but thanks!!

Comment: @AnaLuizaTavares You have a nested list. Using a single `for` "cycle" will not help you much...

Answer (score -1):

Not the most elegant "pythonic" way, but using your code

```
new_lista = {}
for lista in p:
    for i in lista: 
        new_lista[i[0]] = new_lista.get(i[0], 0) + i[1]

p1 = [(k,v) for k,v in new_lista.items()]
```

Answer (score -1):

A horrible one-liner after the import, but it does the trick!

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: dict((k, v + y[k]) for k, v in x.items()), [dict(i) for i in input])
{'Lista-A': 8, 'Lista-X': 3, 'Lista-Z': 9}
```